# Windows and Debian dual boot menu order?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, grub2, elementary-os

I have debian(elementary os) and windows installed on my lap. In the boot menu, every time I'm getting debian os first and it will automatically load after 5 seconds. How can I change the order to windows first?

Comment: go into bios and  change the order

Comment: Both os in the same hard drive. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes do a Google search for how to enter bios for you computer, I have 2 os installed just like you what I do to switch between the two I press f12 as soon the  computer boot which brings me to bios and then I pick which os I want to boot up.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record Elementary OS != Debian, it might be similar in some ways, but it's unlikely that they only changed the name.

Look at your grub configuration, typically found in `/etc/grub` or `/etc/grub.d`, it's probably just a matter of changing the order of things in it. On my machine (that runs Debian exclusively, so I can't test, but if elemtary OS doesn't change how grub is setup it could be similar), I'm guessing I should rename `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` to e.g. `etc/grub/07_os-prober`.